# How can I measure the charge of a pulse imposed on a signal?

Tags: charge, discharge, partial-discharge

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXPLZB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hello All,
So my question is regarding how I can determine the charge of the square voltage source. For example, I need to build a detector that would detect when the pulse of the square wave is at 50 pico Coulombs, how would that be calculated. How can I determine the charge of the square wave from its voltage.
The square wave is imposed on the 60Hz voltage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to determine charge. Why do you think you do?

Comment: Voltage is not charge, it is energy per unit of charge (J/C). So it is not clear what you want. Maybe you want to know at which moment the voltage source has displaced 50 pC? And why would you want to know this?

Comment: Thank you for the response, maybe my circuit isn't clear. I am to detect a partial discharge pulse. The test sample can be treated as a capacitor.

Comment: @Bart Basically, I need to build a custom partial discharge detector, just not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Charge, Q, coulombs, is current x time.

$$ Q = I \cdot t $$.

For varying current, to measure charge passing through a point you integrate the current with respect to time.

$$ Q = \int I dt  $$

Your problem will be extracting this from the 60 Hz but you have given no information on the setup.

> Basically, if I have a pulsating current, how can I find how many charges are pulsating, causing this AC current? I want to know how many coulombs are going back and forth. – Sam

To measure the charge going back and forth you need to measure the 40 kHz component of the current. Since it's a square-wave then the charge per half-cycle is given by \$ Q = I_{PEAK} dt = \frac {1}{2}\frac {i_{PEAK}}{40,000} \$.

Comment: Basically, if I have a pulsating current, how can I find how many charges are pulsating, causing this AC current? I want to know how many coulombs are going back and forth.

Comment: See the update.